# how to show all layers with hotkey (emulate numpad enabled)

Tags: modeling

How can I show all layers with a hotkey? ~ key does not work. (correkt key according to blender wiki) https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_HotKeys/3D_View/Object_Mode
 - Because (I have sensei format and a swedish keyboard). 
I want to quickly be able to view a background image only, hiding all objects, in use when sculpting to see my ref image for one second. - this is possible with show all layers hotkey, and so how can i find or change the hotkey for show all layers in the user pref? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First check that you aren't in [local view](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/3d_view.html#local-view) as this disables the 3Dview layers. When in local view you won't see the layer buttons in the 3Dview header and if you have the view name at the top of the viewport you will see `(local)` there.

You can find the shortcut settings in the [Input Preferences](https://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/input.html), if you enter `layers` into the search box you will see a list of actions involving layers with the shortcut keys, clicking the key will allow you to change the shortcut used and then you can click Save User Settings to enable that shortcut each time you start blender.

[image: Input Prefs]

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>`</kbd> key (tilde) should work with *Emulate Numpad* activated. It might have been remapped to something else, refer to the [answer by @sambler](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/61695/1245) for relevant details.

There are several other ways to work out this problem:

#### Use the Local View on some empty object

> Local view isolates the selected object or objects, so that they are the only ones visible in the viewport.

[Local View](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/navigate/3d_view.html#local-view)

1. Add an emtpy from <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Empty*.
2. With it selected, press <kbd>Numpad Slash</kbd> on the keyboard (if *Emulate Numpad* is used, <kbd>/</kbd> button is accessible for that).

The viewport will enter Local View for the empty object; as it is small and doesn't reflect any geometry it won't mess around in the scene. The background reference image will be available for fast and easy previewing.

Note:

- you can also use any object from the scene for that; select it and enter Local View.
- this way is accessible from the keyboard, however you should have some dummy object for it to work.

#### Use background image settings

[Background images](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/display/background_images.html#settings) can be set up to be visible behind the scene objects or in front of them.

> **Front / Back**
>
> Choose whether the image is shown behind all objects, or in front of everything.

[image: screenshot of background images behind or in front of]

Note:

- in order image to fully cover the objects the *Opacity* setting should be increased to 1 (or something higher than default).
- this setting is inaccessible from the shortcut; you'll need to use *Background Images* rollout a lot from the *Properties* shelf.

Answer (score 0):

The default key for "show all layers" on a Swedish keyboard is Ö.